# How to set up L2TP client on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ipsec, l2tp

I did the basics dependencies

```
sudo apt install network-manager 
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt install network-manager-strongswan
```

But I have a lot of questions:

1. Which IP I should put in Gateway option? I mean, I have an SSH digital ocean server, should I need to download those same dependencies there?
2. How can I get my pre-key from my SSH server?

Comment: Aside from the question, on 18.04 next are also useful, and may be required too on 20.04 : strongswan and libcharon-extra-plugins (which brings along libstrongswan-extra-plugins).